# Should I get my cat spayed/neutered now?

Tags: cats, behavior, health, training

I'm trying get my cat to be house cat again. But should I get him spayed or neutered first? I know where take him. But I'm scared he bite the doctor? Should I take him? Cause they are professional so they know what to do with cat that bite if it gets scared. Or Should I wait and train him , so he won't bite? I know getting him neutered now will make less irritating.

Comment: Being bitten is an occupational risk for doctors. They know how to avoid it , without harming the cat. As you say, they're professionals.

Answer (score 5):

Take him to get neutered now!  We have several [existing questions and answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desexing+cats) about spaying and neutering cats, you might want to browse them.

As you note in your question, the vet is a professional who know how to handle your cat.  All of your listed training goals will be **MUCH** easier once he is neutered.